# Remove all different string on dataframe using fuzzywuzzy

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, fuzzy-search, fuzzywuzzy

I want to remove all different string from a dataframe and retain all "similar" string.

For example, I have this data:

```
store_name
------------
Mcdonalds
KFC
Burger King
Mcdonald's
Mcdo
Taco bell
```

The store that we need to compare above is the first row which is `Mcdonalds`. With that, we need to remove other stores and retain all stores similar to the store we are checking.

Here is the expected output:

```
store_name
------------
Mcdonalds
Mcdonald's
Mcdo
```

The process will continue until it checks the `Taco bell`.

By comparing string similarity, I am using `fuzzy-wuzzy` library. If we compare two string and it gives 90+ similarity ratio, then we tag it as similar string. But how can I filter out the whole dataframe using drop?

From two string comparison:

```
ratio = fuzz.token_set_ratio(string_1, string_2)
```

To filtering whole dataframe:

```
    # TODO: ERROR on this since we are comparing dataframe, not string.
    for index, row in data_df.iterrows():
        copied_data_df = data_df.copy()
        store_name = data_df['store_name']
        copied_data_df.drop(fuzz.token_set_ratio(store_name, copied_data_df) >= 90, inplace=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

So, with the following dataframe:

```py
import pandas as pd

from fuzzywuzzy import fuzz

df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "store_name": [
            "Mcdonalds",
            "KFC",
            "Burger King",
            "Mcdonald's",
            "Mcdo",
            "Taco bell",
        ]
    }
)
```

You can do this:

```py
# Calculate similarities between first row value and other rows
# and save corresponding indexes in a new column "match"
df["match"] = df["store_name"].map(
    lambda x: [
        i
        for i, _ in enumerate(df["store_name"])
        if fuzz.ratio(x, df.loc[0, "store_name"]) > 80
    ]
)

# Select row match and clean up
df["match"] = df["match"].apply(lambda x: x if len(x) > 0 else pd.NA)
df = df.dropna().drop(columns="match").reset_index(drop=True)
```

Which outputs:

```py
print(df)

   store_name
0   Mcdonalds
1  Mcdonald's
2        Mcdo
```